# Error in finding frequency of an input signal

Tags: arduino-uno, digital

Here is my code to find the frequency of an input rectangular wave at pin 8 of the Arduino Uno board.

```
const uint16_t freqPin = PB0;
const uint16_t load = 0;
unsigned long int count=0;
unsigned int value=0;

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
DDRB = 0x00;
TCCR1A = 0;
TCCR1B = TCCR1B & B11111000 | B00000111;
TCNT1 = load;
TIMSK1 |= (1<<ICIE1);
TIMSK1 |= (1<<TOIE1);
sei();
}

void loop()
{
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect){

  count++;
}
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect){
  value = TCNT1;
  TCNT1 = load;
  Serial.println(count);
  Serial.println(value);
}
```

The output is

```
0  
0  
0  
0  
0
```

Why the output is showing zeroes only. why is this happening ? Can someone explain?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add something to differentiate *which* ISR is printing which "0". That may give some clues.

Comment: I have edited the OVF ISR where the `Serial.print` command was written mistakenly.

Comment: As I remember, `Serial` doesn't work inside of an ISR. Am I wrong?

Comment: What frequency range are you hoping to measure?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to measure the frequency of the incoming signal.  Here are ideas based on the assumption that's all you want, rather than to use specific pins of the Arduino:

- Use timer interrupts and `digitalRead(8);` (or faster `(PINB & _BV(0))`) to sample when the signal is high or low.  Transfer the data off Arduino, e.g. to a PC, then do a Fourier transform (Matlab, Mathematica, Excel, whatever you like).  Alternatively, calculate the frequency on-board.  This way it is possible to measure frequencies up to several tens of kHz, with a precision of few Hz.
- Use `attachInterrupt()` on either digital pins 2 or 3.  Count the number of rising edges of the square wave within a given time period.  You can use the timer if you need accuracy, but the method will not be as good as Fourier transform.